# How to create an import library for kernel32.dll using a .def file on x86?

Tags: visual-c++, x86, dllimport, kernel32, import-libraries

I have a small project that does not depend on the CRT or windows sdk. In order to link against kernel32.dll I created a minimal .def file with only the couple functions I need:

```
LIBRARY kernel32.dll
EXPORTS
ExitProcess
```

I then create the .lib during the build with this command:
`lib /DEF:kernel32.def /OUT:kernel32.lib /MACHINE:x86`.

The declaration of the function in my code looks like this:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
__declspec(dllimport) __declspec(noreturn) void __stdcall ExitProcess(UINT uExitCode);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This works perfectly fine when compiling and linking for x64 (with a a lib created with /MACHINE:x64) but when I switch over to x86 I get an unresolved symbol error for `__imp__ExitProcess@4`.

This linker error is resolved by  changing the name of the export in the def file to `ExitProcesss@4` but when running the program, an error appears saying `The procedure entry point 'ExitProcess@4' was not found in MyProgram.exe`.

Everything works fine if I link against the kernel32.lib from the windows sdk. So the issue must be somewhere between creating the def file and creating an import library.

The only reference I could find was a .def file from mingw which looks exactly like mine: https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/lib32/kernel32.def
Although since this file is probably consumed by mingw tools it might have a different output than the lib tool from msvc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have only *def* file is not enouth in case *x86* here.

if will be name `ExitProcess` in def - will be exactly `__imp_ExitProcess` in lib too. but client wait for `__imp__ExitProcess@4`. so you fail at build time.

if you set `ExitProcess@4` your PE will be import `_ExitProcess@4` from *kernel32.dll* and fail at runtime

solution here use *c/cpp/asm* file in conjunction with *def*

minimal solution: first use such *kernel32.asm*

```
.686
.model flat

.code

_ExitProcess@4 proc
_ExitProcess@4 endp

end
```

and compile it as `ml /c /Cp kernel32.asm`

def is simply

```
EXPORTS
ExitProcess
```

and finally use next command

```
link /DLL /NOENTRY /MACHINE:x86 /def:kernel32.def kernel32.obj
```

after this you got correct *kernel32.lib* ( *kernel32.dll* and *kernel32.exp* simple for delete)

Comment: Thank you, that works. Could you maybe explain why you need to do it that way for x86? I would assume it should be possible to create an import library from a def file alone.